# Discoverability of bluetooth device during Inquiry

Tags: bluetooth, java-me, bluetooth-device-discovery

On my device bluetooth properties give

> System.getProperty("bluetooth.sd.trans.max");

as 1.
It is not found by other device while it is making an inquiry itself.
I want to my device to be discoverable while its doing inquiry.
Is this possible ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Inquiry is prioritised over inquiry/page scan on most devices, so no: scanning probably stops during the inquiry process, and you won't be discoverable.